# Live Audio Streaming From Android

Tags: android

Any idea how do I implement live audio streaming from Android 2.x 7 Android 4.x devices to a backend.

Can I use an app like the VLC player to be the backend? How do I establish a connection from the device to the backend and start the audio streaming?

Answer (score 3):

`MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();`
`mp.setDataSource(context,Uri.parse("your url"));`
`mp.prepare();`
`mp.start();'`

Comment: Any idea how to set the VLC player to be the server to connect to?

Comment: No idea. But you can look for code that invokes another application. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html